# Best tool/practice to debugging React-Native UI issues

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I am new to React-Native, I google a lot but didn't get any proper solution. Is there any tool/practice to debugging React-Native UI issues in the best way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Inspector from Debugging mode for UI.
As mentioned in [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.60/debugging#integration-with-react-native-inspector)

But, If your problem with backend, then console.log would be your right hand.

[image]